# react native push notification not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to use react-native-push-notification in my task management app but it isn't popping up, it does not show any error just doesn't pop up. This is my first time using this notification library.
This is my useContext code, it's where I have this issue:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { checkNotifications, requestNotifications } from 'react-native-permissions';
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';

import uuid from 'react-native-uuid';


export const TaskContext = createContext();

export function useTasks() {
  return useContext(TaskContext)
}
export const TaskProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
  const [history, sethistory] = useState([])
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState('');
  console.log(tasks)

  const handleSearchChange = (query) => {
    setSearchQuery(query);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    createChannels();
    requestPushNotificationPermission();
}, []);

const createChannels = () => {
  PushNotification.createChannel({
      channelId: "alarm-channel",
      channelName: "Alarm Channel",
  });
};
const requestPushNotificationPermission = async () => {
  const permissionStatus = await checkNotifications();
  if (permissionStatus.status === 'denied') {
      await requestNotifications(['alert', 'sound']);
  }
}
  const addTask = ({ name, description, date, time }) => {
    const newTask = {
      id: uuid.v4(),
      name,
      description,
      date: date.toLocaleDateString(),
      time: time.toLocaleTimeString(),
    };

    setTasks(prevTasks => {
      return [...prevTasks, newTask]
    });
    const fireDate = date && time;
    // Schedule the notification
    PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
      /* Android Only Properties */
      channelId: "alarm-channel",
      id: newTask.id, // (optional) Valid unique 32 bit integer specified as string. default: Autogenerated Unique ID
      ticker: "My Notification Ticker", // (optional)
      date: new Date (fireDate),
      autoCancel: true, // (optional) default: true
      largeIcon: "ic_launcher", // (optional) default: "ic_launcher"
      smallIcon: "ic_notification", // (optional) default: "ic_notification" with fallback for "ic_launcher"
      bigText: `${newTask.name}\n${newTask.description}`, // (optional) default: "message" prop
      subText: "Task Reminder", // (optional) default: none
      importance: PushNotification.Importance.HIGH,
      color: "red", // (optional) default: system default
      vibrate: true, // (optional) default: true
      vibration: 300, // vibration length in milliseconds, ignored if vibrate=false, default: 1000
      tag: 'some_tag', // (optional) add tag to message
      group: "group", //
      actions: ["Snooze", "Stop Alarm"],
      playSound: true,
      allowWhileIdle: true,
      invokeApp: true,
    });
  }

    function deleteTasks({ id }) {
      setTasks(prevTasks => {
        return prevTasks.filter(task => task.id !== id)
      });
      PushNotification.cancelLocalNotifications({ id: id })
    }


    const addHistory = (todo) => {
      if (!history.some(prevHistory => prevHistory.id === todo.id)) {
        sethistory([...history, todo]);
      }
    };

    function deleteHistory({ id }) {
      sethistory(prevHistory => {
        return prevHistory.filter(his => his.id !== id)
      });
    }

    function updateTask(updatedTask) {
      // Update the task in state
      setTasks(tasks.map(task => task.id === updatedTask.id ? updatedTask : task));
    };


    const filteredTasks = tasks.filter((task) => task.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery.toLowerCase()));

    const filteredHistory = history.filter((his) => his.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery.toLowerCase()));



    return (
      <TaskContext.Provider value={{
        tasks,
        setTasks,
        history,
        sethistory,
        addTask,
        addHistory,
        updateTask,
        deleteTasks,
        deleteHistory,
        filteredTasks,
        filteredHistory,
        handleSearchChange
      }}>
        {children}
      </TaskContext.Provider>
    );
  };
```

This is the HomeScreen Where each task should be displayed (Thus works but I don't know if I need to add any code here):

```
import { HStack } from '@react-native-material/core';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, SectionList, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import TasksModal from '../components/TasksModal';
import colors from '../constants/color';
import { useTasks } from '../context/TodoContext';

export default function HomeScreen() {
    const Task = ({ todo }) => {
        return (
            <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
                <HStack>
                    <View>
                        <Text style={styles.nameText}>{todo?.name}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.descriptionText} numberOfLines={1}>{todo?.description}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View>
                        <Text style={styles.dateStyle}>{todo?.date}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.timeStyle}>{todo?.time}</Text>
                    </View>
                </HStack>
            </View>
        );
    };
    const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(null);
    const { updateTask, tasks } = useTasks();

    const handleItemPress = (item) => {
        setSelectedItem(item)
    }

    const handleSave = (editedTodo) => {
        updateTask(editedTodo);
    };

    return (
        <SafeAreaView>
            <View>
                <SectionList
                    sections={[{ title: 'Tasks', data: tasks }]}
                    keyExtractor={(todo) => todo.id}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleItemPress(item)}>
                            <Task todo={item} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    )}
                    ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={{ height: 1, backgroundColor: colors.light, }} />}
                />
                {selectedItem && (
                    <TasksModal
                        todo={selectedItem}
                        onClose={() => setSelectedItem(null)}
                        onSave={handleSave}
                        isHome={true}
                    />
                )}
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    innerContainer: {
        paddingVertical: 30,
        backgroundColor: colors.white,
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        flexDirection: 'column',
    },
    nameText: {
        color: colors.green,
        fontSize: 26,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        marginHorizontal: 20,
        width: 250,
    },
    descriptionText: {
        color: colors.black,
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: '400',
        width: 250,
        marginHorizontal: 20,
    },
    dateStyle: {
        color: colors.grey,
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textAlign: 'right',
        width: 100,
    },
    timeStyle: {
        textAlign: 'right',

    },
});
```

This is the App.js code:

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import React from 'react';
import { TaskProvider } from './context/TodoContext';
import RootNavigator from './navigator/RootNavigator';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <TaskProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <RootNavigator />
      </NavigationContainer>
    </TaskProvider>

  )
}
```

and this is the Index.js code:

```
/**
 * @format
 */

import PushNotificationIOS from "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios";
import { AppRegistry, Platform } from 'react-native';
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';
import App from './App';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';

PushNotification.configure({
    onRegister: function (token) {
        console.log("TOKEN:", token);
    },

    onNotification: function (notification) {
        console.log("NOTIFICATION:", notification);
        notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
    },
    channelid: 'alarm-channel',
    onAction: function (notification) {
        console.log("ACTION:", notification.action);
        console.log("NOTIFICATION:", notification);

        // process the action
    },

    onRegistrationError: function (err) {
        console.error(err.message, err);
    },

    permissions: {
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true,
    },
    popInitialNotification: true,
    requestPermissions: Platform.OS === 'ios'
});


AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

I am trying to use the react-native-push-notification to send an alarm like notification to the use when it is time for a particular task but when it's time for the task the notification does not appear.